# Unable to register VM node using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am unable to register the node using selenium grid through VM. Below are the steps that I followed while registering a node

1. Started Selenium Hub using the below command

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub
   ```
2. Opened the browser and navigated to the below link.I was able to view the console

   ```
   http://localhost:4444/grid/console
   ```
3. Started the VM and tried registering the node using the below Command

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -port 5555 -hub http://xx.xx.1.28:4444/grid/register
   ```

I am getting the below error

> 17:32:02.960 INFO - couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request.

Note: My Machine's IP: xx.xx.1.28
        VM IP is: xx.xx.1.8

I am able to ping between my machine and VM, not sure what is the issue.

When I try to register the Node from my local it works fine, I am getting the above issue only when I run it through VM.

I also verified the firewall is turned off.

Comment: Can you ping the vm from your machine?

Comment: Yes I am able to do both ways

Comment: Instead of using `-role webdriver` use `-role node` Also check 5555 port is unused. Try to register without defining port.

Comment: Tried but stil getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer, but here is what i did and it worked perfectly :

On the hub machine run :

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub`

On the Vm run :
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.1.28:4444/grid/register`